# Getting a value from li

Tags: jquery

I have a list like this

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block pull-left" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

    <li value="http://www.example.com/" role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Example</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

and Im trying to get the value "http://wwww.example.com" from the li item using this jquery code

```
$(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

but the jquery is selecting the a element because the $(this).val() is showing up as 0 and the $(this).text() is 'Example'. How do I get the value of the li element? I tried jquerys .parent() but that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to grab it as an attribute because it is not a form element:

```
console.log($(this).attr('value'));
```

Comment: This is not really recommended because `value` is not a valid attribute for `LI`; `data-value` should be used instead.

Comment: @naomik That is not correct at all - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li - `value` is a valid attribute, and while normally it should only have a numeric value, because this is an unordered list the `value` property is meaningless, so it is safe to use with a non-numeric property in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

`value` isn't a valid attribute on `li` - you should be using custom `data-*` attributes to pass validation:

```
<li data-value="http://www.example.com/" role="presentation">
```

And then do:

```
var site = $(this).data("value");
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know `.data` would read form `data-*` attributes too. I thought you had to do `.attr("data-value")`.